# Entanglement across a bi-partition of a many particle system

Tags: entanglement

Alice and Bob each have two qubits labelled $A', A$ and $B, B'$ respectively. The density operator of the total system is $\rho_{A'ABB' } \in \mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2 $.

I want to find the amount of entanglement in the $A'A : BB'$ bi-partition. Is it correct to think of Alice's and Bob's total system as a system of two qudits so that the density operator of the total system is now given by $\rho_{\mathbf{AB}} \in \mathcal{H}^4 \otimes \mathcal{H}^4$. Disregarding any structure of Alice's and Bob's subsystems,  as I am not interested in the amount of entanglement present in the subspaces of Alice and Bob individually?

What would be a suitable entanglement measure for the above scenario apart from Rungta's $I \  concurrence$ defined in https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.042315?

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/706842/58382)***

Comment: I'd say the answer is pretty much *yes*, that's what entanglement of $\rho$ with respect to the $A'A:BB'$ bipartition means. You can quantify it using any measurement you'd use for bipartite higher-dimensional systems. Of course, which one you use will depend on situations and e.g. whether the state is pure. A classical reference in this context is https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803